# Select columns larger than a value

Tags: r

My question seems rather simple, but I looked through many answers and didn't find the proper one. So I have a small data as shown below and I want the "count_36" to find only contain columns that are larger than 36. My code is below

```
count_36 <- df[,which(df[,1:19] > 36)]
```

The data is shown below:

```
> A      B  D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O   P   Q   R   S   T
> 192   12  84  72  84  84  84  84  84  84  60  12  12  36  84  84  84  60  84
```

Yet the result also include column B. I'm not sure why. Can any of you correct me? Thanks!

Comment: Since you're looking for a fix, this worked `df[,which(df[,1:18]>36)]` **output** `192 84 72 84 84 84 84 84 60 84 84 84 60 84`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one also works

```
df <-data.frame(A=192,B=12,D=84,E=72,F=84,H=84,I=84,J=84,K=84,L=60,M=12,N=12,O=36,P=84,Q=84,R=84,S=60,T=84)

df[, df[,1:length(df)] > 36]
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. Could you please shed some lights over why my solution doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
df[,apply(df,2,max)>36]
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(A=192,B=12,D=84,E=72,F=84,H=84,I=84,J=84,K=84,L=60,M=12,N=12,O=36,P=84,Q=84,R=84,S=60,T=84)
```

#### output

```
df[,apply(df,2,max)>36]

#     A  D  E  F  H  I  J  K  L  P  Q  R  S  T
# 1 192 84 72 84 84 84 84 84 60 84 84 84 60 84
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `arr.ind = TRUE` with `which` to extract the indices (rows as well as columns) of elements in `df` which are greater than 36. Then, use the unique values in the second column `[,2]` of the indices to subset `df`

```
#DATA
df = read.table(strip.white = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE,
text = "A      B  D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O   P   Q   R   S   T
        192   12  84  72  84  84  84  84  84  84  60  12  12  36  84  84  84  60  84")

df[unique(which(df > 36, arr.ind = TRUE)[,2])]
#    A  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  P  Q  R  S  T
#1 192 84 72 84 84 84 84 84 84 60 84 84 84 60 84
```

Comment: There is an error message: object 'arr.ind' not found

Comment: Actually, my bad. It works. I miss typed the equal sign.